# How to get table carousal jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am able to use jquery for image caraousal but my requirement is to slide table format .Any help will be of great use ..

My code is :

```
<ul>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small1.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview1"/></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small2.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview2"\></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small3.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview3"\></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small1.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview1"\></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small2.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview2"\></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small3.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview3"\></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small1.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview1"\></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small2.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview2"\></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\productdetailshoe_small3.png" alt="Shoecolorthumbview3"/></a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images\imageSlider\Desert.jpg"/></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item">…</div>
<div class="item">…</div>
<div class="item">…</div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.carousel').carousel()
  </script>
```

in

```
<div class="item">…</div>//in this div you can put what ever you want
```